# Laravel 5: How do I connect to AWS Elasticsearch Service?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

So far, I have a basic application in Laravel 5.4, on PHP 7.1, running on an EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I'm also using AWS Elasticsearch Service, which is active with data.

I've read through [the popular guide by Mitch Stanley](https://fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch), but since I'm new to Laravel, and the guide lacks code examples for the model and controller, I'm stuck.

I got as far as:

```
namespace App;

use Elasticquent\ElasticquentTrait;

class VenuesElasticsearch extends Eloquent
{
    use ElasticquentTrait;
}
```

... but that [chokes on `Eloquent`](https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent/issues/146), which I suspect is me not knowing what I'm doing.

Eloquent *appears* to require the installation of Elasticsearch (which isn't feasible on the instance we're using), and I thought it would be possible to skip that and use the AWS endpoint instead?

So this is more a plea: Does anyone know how to connect Laravel 5.4 to the AWS Elasticsearch Service?

Comment: have you find solution for your problem ? I have same configuration as you and have same problem. If you have found solution can you share ?

Comment: @Dhaval, I had to abandon the entire thing and switch to FULLTEXT instead.